# What would be the fastest way to downscale images in bulk without losing much detail?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have 127,658 images of size 1024x1024, the majority of which are in png form (only 56 are jpeg & jpg). After doing some research, I realized that not all resizing methods work the same way, and there are certain methods to follow in the case where maintaining image quality is essential.

If all the paths for the images are in a pandas dataframe, say `df['filepaths']`, then what would be the fastest way to downscale these images? (planning to downscale to 512x512) It could either be CPU or GPU based.

Also, I am doing this assuming that it would reduce the training time for the neural-net (and for experimenting on model accuracies). Would this method of feeding the resized images help in reducing train time, or would it be better to feed the neural net the original images and resize them in the input pipeline?

Any help is much appreciated!

Package versions:
python: 3.7.7,
TensorFlow-gpu: 2.1.0,
Pytorch: 1.6.0
(In different environments, of course)

Hardware info:
CPU: i7-10750H,
GPU: RTX 2060 Mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use various interpolation methods to find which one satisfies you, actually. In the following [link](https://chadrick-kwag.net/cv2-resize-interpolation-methods/) Chadrick told the story well. You may want to check it out and

1024x1024 = 1.048.576
512x512   = 262.144

Exactly 1/4 of an image. You—%100, save yourself some time. As a matter of fact, ImageDataGenerator class of TF's Keras API lets you read images as any size you want. For example, if you'd like to get them from a data frame:

```
ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_dataframe(
    dataframe,
    directory=None,
    x_col="filename",
    y_col="class",
    weight_col=None,
    target_size=(512, 512), # Size parameter
    color_mode="rgb",
    classes=None,
    class_mode="categorical",
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    seed=None,
    save_to_dir=None,
    save_prefix="",
    save_format="png",
    subset=None,
    interpolation="nearest", # Interpolation method parameter
    validate_filenames=True,
    **kwargs
)
```

Answer (score 0):

See Image class of PIL library. It contain more methods for work with image. In particular
there is resize() method.

[Image Class Documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/Image.html)